# Setting httpOnly false in tomcat.

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have grails application, in which I need to set `httpOnly` to `false`, so that I can access the `JSESSIONID` from the client side.

I have used `install-templates` and got the `web.xml` in the project.

There I have added:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>20160</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>false</http-only>
        <secure>false</secure>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

and started the grails server. But still from the client side, I couldn't able to get the `JSESSIONID`.

Where I'm making mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this on Tomcat 7?

Comment: I'm using grails 2.3. So I'm not sure, which version of tomcat does it use.

Comment: So that would be "Yes" if you are using the defaults. In that case then you should read the section in this link http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2010/08/11/security-misconfigurations-java-webxml-files about HttpOnly flag and pay attention to the fact server.xml has settings in Tomcat 7 that need to be modified. If you are using the Tomcat plugin then you will need to configure it programatically which you can read more about here: http://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/grails-tip-configuring-embedded-tomcat-instance-used-in-developmenttest-env/

Comment: The above two links should lead you towards a solution. For completeness here is the documentation for Tomcat 7 so you can see/verify the settings: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: Also, I should note that what you are doing is considered a bad practice and exposes your session to XSS attacks. You may want to reconsider your approach if you don't want to accept that risk. Just a side note. Good luck!